# How to publish/deploy an Angular universal project with SSR implemented on Windows Server?

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-core, angular-universal, windows-server

We have been stuck in this problem. We are trying to publish Angular universal SSR(Server side rendering) project on to Windows server. Our backend/api's are built on asp.net and they are deployed to windows server and they are working fine. Angular project without implementation of SSR, when deployed works fine.

We embedded our angular SSR project in asp.net core to publish on to windows server. On localhost, application works but again on deployment gives too much errors and we were unable to solve this.

Kindly help if any one has success in publishing Angular universal SSR to windows server?

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBTop.png)

Comment: What kind of errors?

Comment: i have uploaded the image.